# Refresh current page with parameter after adding to cart WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, refresh, hook-woocommerce

Right now I am using this function to redirect to the checkout page after adding a product to cart on my page with product grid:

```
function bbloomer_redirect_checkout_add_cart( $url ) {
$url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) );
return $url;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'bbloomer_redirect_checkout_add_cart' );
```

Instead of this I want the current page to reload with a parameter. For example

`?addedtocart=productname`. Is there any function or hook for it?

EDIT:

When editing the function to this:

```
function bbloomer_redirect_checkout_add_cart( $url ) {
$url = var_dump($url);
return $url;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'bbloomer_redirect_checkout_add_cart' );
```

The output is like this: 
`string(0) "" string(41) "http://URL/winkelmand/"`

Comment: add this code after the `$url =` part of the function: `var_dump($url);` and edit your question with the output

Comment: See my edited question

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
function bbloomer_redirect_checkout_add_cart( $url ) {
   $param = $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'];
   $glue = (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') !== false) ? '&' : '?';
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$glue.'addedtocart='.$param;
   return $url;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'bbloomer_redirect_checkout_add_cart' );
```

Comment: Hi, this navigates to the productpage and the link is as follows:
`URL/product/aquazoo/?addedtocart=98` 
I want it to refresh the product grid page with this link

Comment: instead of REQUEST_URI you need to use the REFERER

Comment: When using REFERER it still goes to the productpage instead of refreshing the current page

Comment: Hi Giacomo M, have you seen my reaction?